# Setting a 0-sized handle size in Terminator

Tags: gnome-terminator

With [Terminator](https://launchpad.net/terminator), I used to be able to set a handle size of `0` between splits with this configuration:

```
[global_config]
  ...
  handle_size = 0
  ...
```

But now, it is not working as expected, and the handle is kind of thick, even when setting the size to `0`. In fact, it seems that changing that value has currently no effect.

[image]

Why is this not working anymore?

Using: Fedora 24, Gnome Shell 3.20.4, Terminator 0.98.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure but in 0.97 version there was bug which tells that with using sudo the handle_size is working properly.

Please check this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator/+bug/1479561).

Comment: That was apparently fixed and no, running Terminator with sudo does not fix the problem.

Comment: Can you run terminator with -d operation and find the handle_size option.

Comment: Yes I can: `ConfigBase::get_item: ConfigBase::get_item: handle_size found in globals: 1`. No more references to `handle_size`, though.

Comment: So, does that mean it is not taking the value of handle _size 0?.

Comment: No, it means it is currently set to 1 (does not matter, as that value is ignored).